# PostgreSQL creating enum of enums

Tags: sql, postgresql, enums

I'm wondering if there is any way to create enum of enums in postgresql 
for example:

```
Animation is an enum of ('stop-motion', 'CGI', 'motion-capture')
```

and

```
movieGenre is an enum of (animation, 'fantasy', 'sci-fi', 'horror')
```

So by this method I can insert something like:

```
insert into movies (name, genre) values
  ('Dawn of the planets of apes', 'motion-capture'),
  ('annabelle', 'horror')`
```

and can have queries like

```
select * from movies where genre is animation
```

Comment: Enums themselves are most of the time better done through a regular 1:n relationship but an enum of enums sounds like a _really_ bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

The `ltree` data type would be the way forward, see the documentation [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/ltree.html). The `ltree` data type is an elegant hierarchical structure for label-type information as in your case. Your label paths would be:

```
animation
animation.stop-motion
animation.CGI
animation.motion-capture
phantasy
sci-fi
horror
```

And your corresponding `INSERT` statement:

```
INSERT INTO movies (name, genre) VALUES
  ('Dawn of the planets of apes', 'animation.motion-capture'),
  ('annabelle', 'horror');
```

And `SELECT` statement:

```
SELECT * FROM movies
WHERE genre <@ 'animation';
```

This `SELECT` statement would return all records that are any of the three animation types.

Note that `ltree` is an extension so your superuser has to `CREATE EXTENSION ltree;` if (s)he hasn't already done so for other purposes.